# How Client verifies the certificate serial number send by the server during TLS handshake?

Tags: ssl, certificate, tls1.2

How the client verifies the serial number from the certificate send the by the server by using the issuer certificate on the client store?

Will the issuer certificate on the client certificate store have all the possible serial numbers of  the certificates it can issue?

Answer (score 1):

The client does not verify the serial number. Instead the client checks if the certificate is issued by a trusted certificate authority by validating the issuers signature on the certificate.

The serial number is involved in checking if the certificate is revoked though within mechanism like CRL, OCSP or others - see [How are Chrome and Firefox validating SSL Certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17656/how-are-chrome-and-firefox-validating-ssl-certificates) for the details.